# ggplot sort descending points within group

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, tidytext

I want to arrange the plot below so that 'group' is arranged in descending order by 'Distance' within Community (Out, In).

[image]

I've tried using `dplyr::arrange` and `tidytext::reorder_within(group, -value, MPA_type)`, but neither of these work - ggplot continues to default to sorted by group name in descending order (see legend). If `facetwrap` is part of the solution, I'd prefer to have the labels at the bottom as in the example figure, rather than the typical facet header.

Here is my data:

```
sig_distance <- structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("ref after", 
"ref before", "ref during", "smr after", "smr before", "smr during"
), class = "factor"), Var2 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 6L), .Label = c("ref after", 
"ref before", "ref during", "smr after", "smr before", "smr during"
), class = "factor"), value = c(0.0781171338765429, 0.070131485880327, 
0.124219180798504, 0.0642584499973571, 0.16882716299913, 0.123057288279708, 
0.185404402405965, 0.113660097900038, 0.14628853013894, 0.106462687516074, 
0.179579889492142, 0.146317072898829, 0.163284273893779, 0.130083096905712, 
0.0991349070859965, 0.106610448830353, 0.0499622399107518, 0.0563330614755333, 
0.0391975833642552, 0.0435817314833789), MPA = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("MPA___before-to-during", "Reference___before-to-during", 
"Reference___before-to-after", "MPA___before-to-after"), scores = structure(c(`MPA___before-to-after` = 0.125507192629372, 
`MPA___before-to-during` = 0.0948855602219911, `Reference___before-to-after` = 0.121295868163829, 
`Reference___before-to-during` = 0.0972135240114708), .Dim = 4L, .Dimnames = list(
    c("MPA___before-to-after", "MPA___before-to-during", "Reference___before-to-after", 
    "Reference___before-to-during"))), class = "factor"), name = c("sd_ref_pooled_before_after", 
"sd_ref_pooled_before_during", "sd_smr_pooled_before_after", 
"sd_smr_pooled_before_during", "sd_ref_pooled_before_after", 
"sd_ref_pooled_before_during", "sd_smr_pooled_before_after", 
"sd_smr_pooled_before_during", "sd_ref_pooled_before_after", 
"sd_ref_pooled_before_during", "sd_smr_pooled_before_after", 
"sd_smr_pooled_before_during", "sd_ref_pooled_before_after", 
"sd_ref_pooled_before_during", "sd_smr_pooled_before_after", 
"sd_smr_pooled_before_during", "sd_ref_pooled_before_after", 
"sd_ref_pooled_before_during", "sd_smr_pooled_before_after", 
"sd_smr_pooled_before_during"), sd_pooled = c(0.0640133632403095, 
0.059224209496302, 0.0418411590759088, 0.0420366263878186, 0.0697371748889264, 
0.0713939572229526, 0.0662209469675998, 0.0673861920919254, 0.0952259175162696, 
0.0973881903133112, 0.104688903793631, 0.104123442035945, 0.0831395386888112, 
0.0736773344066338, 0.0870890086043125, 0.082205340195828, 0.0622386704700814, 
0.0506360166386964, 0.0776340589400514, 0.057490214920967), group = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Group 5", "Group 4", "Group 3", "Group 2", 
"Group 1"), class = "factor"), period = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("Before-to-after", "Before-to-during"), class = "factor"), 
    MPA_type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Out", 
    "In"), class = "factor"), Df = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), SumOfSqs = c(0.644667474362213, 
    0.163718859184403, 0.531883138574452, 0.172377817596512, 
    1.36062525175964, 0.561260198791761, 1.26106114133322, 0.478287656340437, 
    1.12522630961807, 0.502450621711331, 0.779126478533436, 0.349888339609262, 
    0.64822862542131, 0.198815304465667, 0.329502905266225, 0.124876688005652, 
    0.197752601704789, 0.10862759418973, 0.142471900603864, 0.0840130152284379
    ), R2 = c(0.190110542714351, 0.0631029576320754, 0.217228522650464, 
    0.089364183731598, 0.076782933708657, 0.0349456770960147, 
    0.0732327885619086, 0.0303186954655169, 0.0788241854776924, 
    0.0376889492950336, 0.0656167575864088, 0.0312644101580068, 
    0.288412156204619, 0.123882033933067, 0.158350315762715, 
    0.0838360162000489, 0.0226863909348303, 0.0137219062151816, 
    0.0222248102598127, 0.0150399647150649), F = c(9.62419276009816, 
    2.4247130389196, 11.3779943270621, 3.53281801227694, 10.4792794679964, 
    4.27290961706825, 9.00823614929462, 3.37679925864692, 10.610568411745, 
    4.50397942095095, 7.93538804068383, 3.45325589560756, 6.07961811151075, 
    1.83818447230295, 2.44585620771756, 1.18959949296437, 3.29624747150235, 
    1.85040460507006, 2.25026799494279, 1.42007459023087), `p-val` = c(0.001, 
    0.05, 0.001, 0.006, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 0.001, 0.001, 
    0.001, 0.005, 0.001, 0.076, 0.017, 0.31, 0.005, 0.069, 0.037, 
    0.195), sig = c("*", "", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", 
    "*", "*", "*", "*", "", "*", "", "*", "", "*", "")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Plotting code:

```
p1 <- 
  sig_distance %>%
  rename("Period"=period)%>%
  filter(Period == "Before-to-during")%>%
  mutate(group = factor(group))%>%
  arrange(MPA_type, -value, group)%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=reorder(MPA_type, -value), y=value, color=group, 
             #shape=group, 
             #fill=MPA_type
             ))+
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width=0.8),
             size=3)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-sd_pooled,
                    ymax = value+sd_pooled), stat="identity",
                position = position_dodge(width=0.8), size=0.3, width=.3)+
  #add significance level
  geom_text(aes(label=sig), size=5, vjust=-0.01,
            position = position_dodge(width=0.8),
            show.legend = FALSE)+
  ylab("Distance (Bray-Curtis)")+
  xlab("Community")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        legend.key=element_blank())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to add a helper column to you dataset as the interaction of `MPA_type` and `group` for which you set the order using `forcats::fct_inorder` after you arranged your dataset according to your desired order. Thus helper column could then be mapped on the `group` aes:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

sig_distance %>%
  rename("Period" = period) %>%
  filter(Period == "Before-to-during") %>%
  mutate(group = factor(group)) %>%
  arrange(MPA_type, -value, group) %>%
  mutate(mpa_ordered = fct_inorder(paste(MPA_type, group, sep = "."))) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = MPA_type, y = value, color = group, group = mpa_ordered)) +
  geom_point(
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.8),
    size = 3
  ) +
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(
      ymin = value - sd_pooled,
      ymax = value + sd_pooled
    ),
    stat = "identity",
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), size = 0.3, width = .3
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = sig),
    size = 5, vjust = -0.01,
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.8),
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  ylab("Distance (Bray-Curtis)") +
  xlab("Community") +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
    legend.key = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]